# Getting geometry of QListView icon on doubleClick in order to do animation

Tags: qt

I have a photobrowser using a QListView in iconMode. When a photo thumbnail is doubleclicked I show a QWidget with the full size image.

I'd like to animate the display of the full size image, zooming out from the location of the clicked icon but I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the geometry. The routine I am using to show the image is at bottom. I've been playing with trying to access the geometry without success. I've tried a few things with the selectionModel() but I think this is wrong. What's the obvious thing I am missing?

```
    QItemSelection sel = thumbView->selectionModel()->selection();
    qDebug() << "sel.count()" <<  sel.count();
    QItemSelectionRange selItem = sel.first();
    qDebug() << "selItem" << selItem.left() <<selItem.top()<< selItem.right()<< selItem.bottom();
```

Once I get the geometry I'll do a QPropertyAnimation from the icon size to the MainWindow size.

---

```
void ImageBase::displayImageFullsize(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QSqlRecord record = imageModel->record(index.row());

    QByteArray image_data = record.value(3).toByteArray();

    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap();
    pixmap.loadFromData(image_data);

    imageView->setPixmap(pixmap);
    imageView->setMinimumSize(QSize(1024,768));
    imageView->adjustSize();
    imageView->show();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get QRect of your item in view with [visualRect ( const QModelIndex & index )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#visualRect)

Example:

```
void UrlView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) // Derived from QAbstractItemView
{
    QModelIndex index = indexAt(event->pos());
    QRect rect = visualRect(index);
    qDebug() << rect;
}
```

Now you should have position of item relative to parent widget.
Then you should get position of image in that item and calculate position relative to MainWindow.

Some of these can help

[QPoint     mapToParent ( const QPoint & pos ) const](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapToParent)

[QPoint     mapFromParent ( const QPoint & pos ) const](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapFromParent)